# Library parallax.js

Tags: javascript, css, background, parallax.js

Hello I'm using the following library: http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/ and I have a problem.

I am attached as my image and how I want it to look me

[Image with problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztVLz.jpg)

My code is:

Html:

```
<div class="parallax-window" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/recursos/imagenes/parallax-home.jpg"></div>
```

Css

```
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update your css to have a width value, such as:

```
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If that doesn't work, try setting the positioning in the css, such as:

```
.parallax-window {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem remains .

The image is already 100% , but not enlarged and because .